# Variable returning value of previously entered element in java arraylist

Tags: java

I'm trying create a program that use dialog boxes and stores elements in Object Goals(string, int, int). This is just a home project I've decided to do during Uni holidays.

So far it's working how I planned but there is one bug I can't figure out.

```
//asks user to input goals and stores them in an array list

public static void setup(){

int n = 0;
int i = 0;
boolean setupFinished = false;
boolean success = false;
List<Goals> setupList = new ArrayList<Goals>();
JOptionPane setupBox = new JOptionPane();
while(!setupFinished){
    Goals goal = new Goals();
    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("A goal you wish to work on?");
        if(str1 == null){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        goal.setGoal(str1);
        String goalPrefInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the initial preference of this goal compare to the others?");
            if(goalPrefInput == null){
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (goalPrefInput.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                n = Integer.parseInt("1");
            } else {    
        while(!success){
            try {
                n = (Integer.parseInt(goalPrefInput));
                success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception NumberFormatException){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid number");       
                        }
                    }
                }
            goal.setGoalPref(n);
            System.out.println(goal.getGoalPref());
            success = false;
            String goalFreqInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the frequency rate you wish this preference to increase?");
                if(goalFreqInput == null){
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (goalFreqInput.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    n = Integer.parseInt("1");
                } else {                        
            while(!success){
                try {
                    n = (Integer.parseInt(goalFreqInput));
                    success = true;
                    }
                catch (Exception NumberFormatException){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid number");   
                        }
                    }
                }
            goal.setGoalPrefIncrease(n);
            System.out.println(goal.getGoalPrefIncrease());
setupList.add(i, goal);
i++;
int f = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Have you finished setup?", "Setup Finished?", YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(f == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        setupFinished = true;
    }
}
System.out.print(setupList.toString());
String s = removeBrackets(setupList.toString());

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(setupBox, "Here are your goals \n" + s);

    }
}
```

It's not finished but what is happening that I don't understand is that the user will enter the first instance of goal the user will put in - 
goal: a, goalPref: 1, goalFreq: 1. 
Then the second instance they will put in
goal: b, goalPref: 2, goalFreq: 2. 
However for the second instance the goalPref that is suppose to 2 will return 1 whilst goalFreq will return a 2 correctly. If the next instance is
goal: c, goalPref: 3 goalFreq: 3. 
Then it will return c, 2, 3 as the previous goalPref was 2.

The thing that confuses me is the code for entering goalPref and goalFreq is identical so why is one working and one isn't?

Here is the Goals class code:

```
public class Goals {
private String goal;
private int goalPref;
private int goalPrefIncrease;

public String getGoal() {
    return goal;
}
public void setGoal(String goal) {

    this.goal = goal;

}
public int getGoalPref() {
    return goalPref;
}
public void setGoalPref(int goalPref) {
this.goalPref = goalPref;
}
public int getGoalPrefIncrease() {
    return goalPrefIncrease;
}
public void setGoalPrefIncrease(int goalPrefIncrease) {
    this.goalPrefIncrease = goalPrefIncrease;
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
String s = "Goal: " + this.getGoal() + ", Goal Preference: " +      this.getGoalPref() + ", Goal Frequency Rate: " + this.getGoalPrefIncrease(); 
//String s = goal +  ", Goal Preference: " + goalPref + ", Goal Frequency Rate: " + goalPrefIncrease;

return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but your code is a mess.  try moving common blocks of code into methods, so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I suspected as much. Do you mean having a tab for each method or breaking the method down into smaller methods that work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used a debugger to see what is the mistake in your code. The problem here is your `success` variable which holds a key in determining value of `n` for your inputs.

Currently at the end of your loop it is `true` so in next cycle its value is still `true` and after entering goal pref it is not going in your `while(!success)` loop to determine value of `n` so last value of `n`(which is last value of goal frequency you entered) is assigned to new goal pref.

In order to correct it you need to reset value of `success` to false at the start of every iteration.

```
while(!setupFinished){
    success = false;
    Goals goal = new Goals();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I tried using the debugger but I guess I didn't put enough little dots next to the code. Still inexperienced in using it.

Comment: That happens at the start .. glad this helped you .. have fun coding :)